# Move the ImageView to EditTextView

Tags: android

In my application i want displaying the one image as half of the screen and below i am producing that image spelling   and below display that image name letters as shuffled and kid will take one image and place into into that place in above spelling.For example see following website

> //www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LSlYYu3F0k

For this how can i design my layout(xml)Please gice me some code suggestions.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a layout based on xml you wont get a result like that on the video.
You should use 2D/3D based SurfaceView/GLSurfaceView and draw on the canvas what you need and where you need it.

Comment: You should take a look at a tutorial series for 2d programming I have written: http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html (first part)

Comment: Thank u Faith.I am displaying image(bitmap) and according to image i am displaying the name image. and i move that image.But how to compare when i move the letters into particular place.give me some suggestions.

Comment: Basically do some collision detection. A bitmap should have bounds, as far as I know.